# Hidden Field not being sent in Form Collection asp.net MVC

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-2, hidden-field

I have a couple Hidden form fields that are not being sent when I submit the form?  I use the Html Helpers to add the form the page...

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateXML", "PatientACO", new { template = (int)Model, PopPatId = TempData["POPPATID"]}, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "editTemp", id = "temp1" }))
Response.Write("<table width=\"500\" class=\"odd\">");
Html.Hidden("encounter", encounter);
Html.Hidden("AddEnc", encflag);
Response.Write("</table>");   %>
```

Here is the method in my controller...

```
public ActionResult UpdateXML(int template, int PopPatId, FormCollection formCollection)
{
    foreach (var key in formCollection.Keys)
    {
       if (key.ToString() == "deactivate")
       {
                      ((XmlElement)node.SelectSingleNode("//template/elements/element[@name=\"Active\"]")).SetAttribute("value", value);
           if (value == "N")
           {
               dateIn = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yy");
           }                            
       }
       if (key.ToString() == "AddEnc")
       {
           if(formCollection[key.ToString()]=="ADDENC")
                            ((XmlElement)node.SelectSingleNode("//template/elements/element[@name=\"FOCUSED_READMISSIONS_ID\"]")).SetAttribute("value", "0");
       }

    }
}
```

Those two If statements never hit.  Also, when I look at the formCollection Object, I can see that those two fields aren't in there.  How can I make sure that my hidden fields are submitted with the rest of the form?

Comment: are the form fields on the page?

Comment: I actually can't find them in the code behind.  For some reason, they aren't being added to the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few things wrong in that code. If you're trying to mix html with server-side code you shouldn't use `Response.Write`. Also, you need to place the contents of the form inside braces. Try this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateXML", "PatientACO", 
       new { template = (int)Model, PopPatId = TempData["POPPATID"]}, FormMethod.Post,
       new { name = "editTemp", id = "temp1" }))
   { %>
        <table width="500" class="odd">
            <%= Html.Hidden("encounter", encounter) %>
            <%= Html.Hidden("AddEnc", encflag) %>
        </table>
<% } %>
```